# Can't encode chinese properly in console using Rstudio

Tags: mysql, r, encoding, rstudio, rodbc

I am using `RODBC` to connect `mysql` with R like below:

```
library(RODBC)
channel=odbcConnect("MySQL_ODBC_AIRFORECASTSYSTEM",uid="root",pwd = "3896123ray") 
sql="select * from region_station"
ttt=sqlQuery(channel,query = sql)`
```

Ss you can see I've put the result into a data.frame, "ttt", and I can use `View(ttt)` to show the contain, and the Chinese shows properly.

[image]

However, when I use `ttt[,2]` trying to show the second column in console, it became like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The first column is the Chinese, the second column is outcome of mysql's hex(), and the third column is the result in Rstudio's console.

二林站    E4BA8CE69E97E7AB99    鈭\x9e\xab\x99

南投站    E58D97E68A95E7AB99    \xe5\x8d\x8a\xab\x99

埔里站    E59F94E9878CE7AB99    \xe5\x9f\x87\xab\x99

大里站    E5A4A7E9878CE7AB99    憭折\x87\xab\x99

彰化站    E5BDB0E58C96E7AB99    敶啣\x8c\xab\x99

忠明站    E5BFA0E6988EE7AB99    敹\x98\xab\x99

Comment: Please provide:  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table; `SELECT HEX(col) ...` for one of the improperly rendered cells.

Comment: @Rick James, Thanks for the comment. I've checked the Default text encoding in Rstudio, it's utf-8. But the Sys.getlocale() is like this:         [1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950;LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950;LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950" , is that the problem?

Comment: Please paste a Chinese string that does not render correctly.

Comment: I don't think the LC settings are used by MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, Sys.getlocale() is R's command.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with MySQL.  Nor can I imagine where ` 鈭` is coming from.  The `\x..` seems to always be valid bytes from the hex.  I have to think that RStudio is at fault.

Comment: Does "Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950" kinds of codes like utf8 or big5? If so, how can I change it into utf8?

Comment: You may have a point there.  MySQL has `CHARACTER SETs` utf8, utf8mb4 gbk, gb2312, and big5 for Chinese.  Microsoft's "code page 950" is Big5.  Big5 is (I think) a 2-byte encoding for all Chinese characters.  Utf8 needs 3 or sometimes 4 bytes.  The hex you presented is matches the characters you have (as utf8).  大里站 is (I think) hex A46AA8BDAFB8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

950 seems to be Big5.  For example

```
CONVERT(BINARY('大里站') USING big5) --> 憭折
```

which agrees with one of your dumps.

So...

```
SET NAMES big5;
```

(or however you specify the `CHARACTER SET` to MySQL from Rstudio)

or change the LC values to be utf8.